# How to go back to filled fields in a form after a php form is submitted?

Tags: php, forms

- I have a php form
- After filling fields I submit the form
- After submitting form I have in the same window (a pop up) a print (via echo) of strings using variables values previously entered in the form
- I need a way to go back to the form with fields filled by the values entered previously in order to modify or review them and then submit the form again
- My form is created in a proprietary php framework. A field is so defined in a file named base.env:

  ```
        $sf_vaccine['fields']['taxCode'] = new TextField('taxCode');
        $sf_vaccine['fields']['taxCode']->label = 'Codice fiscale';
        $sf_vaccine['fields']['taxCode']->addFlag(Field::NOT_EMPTY());
        $sf_vaccine['sheet']->addField($sf_vaccine['fields']['taxCode']);
  ```

After a research on the web and differents attempts I did this. After submitting the form I print a link to the previous page:

```
echo "<center><a href="javascript:history.back(-1)">Go Back</a></a></center></br></br></br>";
```

It allows me to back to the previous page but fields are empty and not filled as I need

I've also made an attempt using sessions: here what I did:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<center><a href=http://192.168.228.34/it/centre_rm/card_block/?_command=insert&prefill=yes><b>Go Back</b></a></center></br></br></br>";
    $_GET['prefill']=='yes';
    
    $_SESSION['taxCode'] = $record['taxCode'];
    $fields['taxCode']->value = $_SESSION['taxCode'];
```

Comment: Is this an attempt to validate the form in PHP, and if it's not correct the user is prompted to "fill in required fields correctly"? In that case you need to introduce some Ajax calls in your solution... Please let us know if this is the case :)

Comment: ^ Why would ajax be required to solve this? It is not

Comment: As i understand, you need to use php to reprint form content instead of java , php is better for security reasons , all you need is to edit php output to re-echo the form with the post request data instead of empty form as long as there’s post request , so php will only output empty form in case of no post requests.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use javascript history for this, but just go back to the page after submitting the form and add the values to the form.

Something like this:

```php
<?php
$length = '';
$width = '';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_POST['length'])) {
        $length = $_POST['length'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['width'])) {
        $width = $_POST['width'];
    }
    echo "Submitted length '$length' and width '$width'.";
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    Length: <input type="text" name="length" value="<?= $length ?>"/>
    Width: <input type="text" name="width" value="<?= $width ?>"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I've added the echo-statement as sort of confirmation message but this can be removed if not needed.

Because of the `action=""` part, after clicking submit, the same page wil reload. De input values are sent and can be reused on the page reload.

Within the if-statements the submitted values are assigned to a variable to add these again in the input fields within the `value` tag so they are prefilled with the submitted data.

If you'd like to modify the submitted values before adding them to the inputs, you can do this within the if-statements and adjust the data accordingly.

Comment: @DarkBee Thx for comment, I've adjusted it likewise.

Comment: In your code there's: `echo "Submitted length '$length' and width '$width'.";` Well I don't need to print the values but I need to have form fields filled with values entered previously and the capability to modify them. Further, I'm not able to see the instruction to get back to the previous page. Sorry, I'm still a principiant, excuse me if I didn't understand!

Comment: @Marcello D'Ambrosio No problem, I'm here to help. I've updatet my answer with additional explanation.

Comment: Well, I encounter an issue: when I sbmit the form, in the same window it prints some text via echo extracting some values from the values entered previously entered in the form `echo '<b>Descrizione richiesta:</b></br></br>' . $sf_vaccine['fields']['callerId']->toStringValue()`  (example). What kind of instruction do I have to do to go back and landing on the form filled with previous entered valus? I've used your solution, but when using the instruction `href='javascript:history.back(-1)` nothing happens

Comment: My solution shows how to go to the page with the form and how to refill the form with values using `value` tag. You don't need javascript for this. The first part is not really clear to me, can you maybe update your question with more code?